# Image Direction - iOS metadata

Tags: ios, gps, metadata

I am trying to add GPS metadata to an image. I referred this link for how other key values are set. But I am unable to find how I can get 'Image Direction', i.e., the value for the key `kCGImagePropertyGPSImgDirection` and `kCGImagePropertyGPSImgDirectionRef`.
I don't know what 'Image Direction' means, and I don't know where to get the value from. the `location` property of the location manager doesn't have any such property.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `CGImageSourceRef` and `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(...)` to get GPS data, it returns both Image Direction and Image Direction Ref. They are part of Cocoa/Cocoa.h.

Also you can download Apple's ImageApp example to find out how it's used.